# Проблема с инвертированием двоичного кода в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

подскажите пожалуйста, как из числа 0b10000011 я могу получить число 0b01111100 в Python?
Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Попробуйте исключающее или: `print(bin(0b10000011 ^ 0xFF))`.

Comment: @nomnoms12, то что надо, спасибо, сам не догадался)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться исключающим или `^`.

***Пример:***

```py
print(bin(0b10000011 ^ 0xFF))
```

***stdout:***

```py
0b1111100
```

*P. S.:* `0b01111100` = `0b1111100`.

Comment: Как вариант - можно делать через битовое отрицание, но получается на одну операцию больше: `~0b10000011 & 0xFF`